# mkreiserfs block size limit other than in man / info page?

Tags: reiserfs

I have tried to format a partition on an USB pendrive with `mkreiserfs 3.6.21` as follows:

`mkreiserfs --block-size=2048 /dev/sdb1`

Which resulted in

> Block sizes smaller than 4k are not supported.

Interesting, because both `info` and `man mkreiserfs` describe as possible block size:

> `-b | --block-size N`
>         N  is  block  size  in bytes. It may only be set to a power of 2 within the 512-8192 interval.

So I tried it from the other end:

> `mkreiserfs /dev/sdb1 --block-size=8192`

and got:

`Block sizes larger than 4k are not supported on all architectures`.

A bit picky, aren't we… Working with Linux `3.2.0-4-amd64` kernel I've tried the same as before in combination with the `--format` option. Same results.

### Question

*What am I doing wrong?*

Some ideas I came across:

- bad idea to create this on an USB device
- *problem is located in the compiled version of `mkreiserfs`?*
- (*bug in documentation*?)

Yes, I know that `reiser4` was created to replace `reiserfs` and it isn't very common anymore (or could I say "*is defunct*"?).

---

Having little to no idea about `.h` files but at least willing to try to find anything informative, I found this in `/usr/include/linux/reiserfs_fs.h` - not helpful but worth sharing, I guess:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the mkreiserfs did not succeed? The message you got is just a warning.

Comment: how could I know? As far as I was able to figure out with `reiserfsck` all seems ok - as long as I don't change any defaults